# Как получить у объекта в модели значение по строковой переменной? django python

Tags: python, django

**models**

```
class Prints(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Название')
    contentform = RichTextUploadingField()
    related_uuid = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**view**

```
str = 'name'
uuid = 'someuuid'
getObj = Prints.objects.get(Q(related_uuid__icontains=uuid))
takeName = getObj.str # тут ошибка
```

выдает ошибку `'Prints' object has no attribute 'str'`. Вот как получить из объекта поле name по его строковому значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getattr(getObj, "name")

Comment: В этом случае мы получим значение поля, а как получить именно поле, чтобы, допустим, записать в него другое значение?

Comment: @Виталий https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106314/7753445 и https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/meta/#field-access-api

Comment: Спасибо, я уже ознакомился с setattr(obj, "name", value)

Comment: @Виталий А, я вас неправильно понял. Я вам накидал ссылок как получать названия полей.

Comment: Ага, мне немного другое нужно было) Но спасибо большое)